# If-Then Constraint: If X < 4 Then T = 4 -X

Tags: integer, mathematical-optimization

All the generic If-then constraints do not seem to be gaining me any insight into this. 
I would like to form a mixed-integer program with Lindo which can minimize cost given that a series of: When X < 4 Then T = 4 - X & Y = 1. Otherwise, when x > 4, then T = 0 and Y = 0. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What happens to `T` when `X >= 4`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to model this expression we need to know the bounds of `4 - X`. Lets assume that

```
LB <= 4 - X <= UB
```

where `LB <= 0`, `UB >=0` and `|LB| + |UB| > 0` (i.e., not both `LB` and `UB` are zero), else the problem is trivial.

Then we consider the following system (`T` is continuous, `Y` is binary):

```
T >= 4 - X                  (I)
T <= 4 - X - LB * (1 - Y)   (II)
T <= UB * Y                 (III)
T >= 0                      (IV)
```

**Proof of correctness**:

```
X < 4 <=> 4 - X > 0 so (I) => T > 0 and then (III) => Y = 1, 
and (I) + (II) => T = 4 - X. (III, IV) are redundant in this case.

X > 4 <=> 4 - X < 0. If we allow Y = 1 then T = 4 - X < 0, which is not
allowed by (IV). Hence, Y = 0 and (III, IV) => T = 0. (I, II) are redundant in
this case.

X == 4 ==> T = 0 and Y either 0 or 1.
```

I hope this helps!